# Is the 'up' the part of a phrasal verb or an adverb?

Tags: adverbs, phrasal-verbs

> Soon, I worked my thumb into the middle to create a mouth, shaping the
>   sides ***up*** in a curve.

Is the '***up***' the part of a phrasal verb or an adverb?

Comment: I'd say that the PP "up in a curve" is a locative complement of "shape". I don't see a so-called phrasal verb here.

Comment: @BillJ It's true that PP is a complement. But is it really "locative"? I mean it's the shape, by the PP it shows how the shape transformed into. Can we call such complement, a locative complement?

Comment: @Man_From_India Yes, it's more a directional/shape expression, but complements don't have the sub-catagories that adjuncts do (like 'temporal', manner, reason, etc ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the analysis in *CGEL*<sup>†</sup>, Ch.7, §2, *up* here is an intransitive preposition—that is, a preposition which requires no object to act as a preposition phrase (PP).

(If this sort of analysis seems strange to you, compare intransitive verbs, which require no object to act as a predicate: *John ran*.)

*CGEL*, 274, rejects the term 'phrasal verb'—rightly, to my mind. I take *up* here to be a complement of *shaped* acting as a [*secondary predicate*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secondary-predicates) on the Direct Object *the sides*: it names the 'goal' of the shaping and the final location of the sides. The full PP *in a curve* acts the same way.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Huddleston & Pullum, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, 2002</sub>

Comment: Are you saying that 'shaping the sides upwards' ? Or are you saying it's the same usage as 'How are your plans shaping up?/
There is a picture of senior potter shaping up the terracotta clay pot on the wheel.'?

Comment: @whitecap *Shape up* in your 'plans' example is intransitive--the plans 'shape up'--but this is transitive: the potter shapes the sides up. I take it to mean that in the potter moved a portion of the clay sides up(ward) along a curved profile in order to form the mouth.